# Silverlight images not displaying

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, wcf-ria-services, ivalueconverter

I am creating application in Silverlight. There is only a DataGrid right now. I am using WCF RIA Service for getting datas from database. Everything works fine expect Images. I am getting images as byte array and trying to convert them to BitmapImage using Converter. I want to show images in RowDetailsTemplate of DataGrid.

Here it is:

```
    <sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel> 
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image x:Name="thumbNail"  Width="60" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" ImageFailed="thumbNail_ImageFailed"
                           Source="{Binding gameImage,Converter={StaticResource byteToImageConverter}}">
                    </Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

And converter:

```
public class ByteToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitMapImage(byte[] imageByteArray)
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray))
            {
                img.SetSource(memStream);
            }
            return img;
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            if (value != null)
            {
                img = this.ConvertByteArrayToBitMapImage(value as byte[]);
            }
            return img;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But images are not displaying.

The method in my wcf service is like that:

```
   public List<Games> GamesList()
        {
            string gmConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GamesConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            var gamesList = new List<Games>();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(gmConn))
            {
                string sql = @"Select Name, Developer,Longevity,Distributor,Year,State,Type,graphics, gameplay,sound,general,photo From Games join scores on Games.G_ID=Scores.G_ID";
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr != null)
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            Games game = new Games
                            {
                                Name = dr.GetString(0),
                                developer = dr.GetString(1),
                                Longevity = dr.GetInt32(2),
                                Distributor = dr.GetString(3),
                                Year = dr.GetString(4),
                                State = dr.GetString(5),
                                Type = dr.GetString(6),
                                Graphics = dr.GetDouble(7),
                                Gameplay = dr.GetDouble(8),
                                Sound = dr.GetDouble(9),
                                General = dr.GetDouble(10)
                            };
                            if (!dr.IsDBNull(11))
                            {
                                byte[] blob = new byte[(dr.GetBytes(11, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                                dr.GetBytes(11, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    ms.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length - 0);
                                    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
                                    using (MemoryStream msJpg = new MemoryStream())
                                    {
                                        bm.Save(msJpg, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                                        game.gameImage = msJpg.GetBuffer();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            gamesList.Add(game);
                        }
                    return gamesList;
                }
            }
        }
```

And in mainPage.xaml.cs I am setting ItemsSource of my datagrid.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SampleServiceClient client = new SampleServiceClient();

        client.GamesListCompleted += new EventHandler<GamesListCompletedEventArgs>(client_GamesListCompleted);
        client.GamesListAsync();
    }

    void client_GamesListCompleted(object sender, GamesListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you debug and check if image is created in the converter?

Comment: I add breakpoint to Converter class. And then I clicked one of the rows in DataGrid to see image. But app not come to the breakpoint. So, something is wrong. But what?

Comment: How are you setting the DataContext?

Comment: I´m not really sure if its a problem, cause you are using MemoryStream, but you should not dispose the stream that is associated to BitmapImage.

Comment: Check your Output for exceptions, maybe the binding is wrong.

Comment: @Erno I have a Game class with ten properties. And method in WCF Service which is returning List<Games>. And in the completed event of this method I am setting ItemsSOurce of dataGrid.

Comment: @Vale yes you are right. There is error: BindingExpression path error: 'gameImage' property not found on 'SilverlightWithWCFService.CustomerService.Games'.

Comment: Then check the spelling of `GameImage`

Comment: What could be a problem? I have searched google for BindingExpression path error. But found nothing.

Comment: The exception shows that DataContext for the image is 'SilverlightWithWCFService.CustomerService.Games' and not Game as you expected. You need to show us how you set the source of the DataGrid.

Comment: @Vale Yes. The name of the class is GAMES. Now i am going to update my question with that.

Comment: Then 'gameImage' property really does not exist! Check case! I would name my property GameImage (with the capital G).

Comment: I updated my question. The property name is gameImage. I dont think that there is any problem. Yes?

Comment: Looks good to me... Try to add a TextBlock to the StackPanel and bind it to Name for example. If that works, the image should display too.

Comment: I did it. BUt cut it when coping it to here. So yes. All properties expect gameImage is working correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15568/discussion-between-farhad-jabiyev-and-vale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a simple test project with your code and I could not recreate your problem. It might be the case that the byte array is corrupted? (Just a guess..)

Any way, you can find and download the test project here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DEB5DDFF6A505390!278 I have made a simple project with an embedded image. I opened that image and converted it into a byte array. Then I used binding to display the image.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Resources;

namespace SilverlightTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("SilverlightTest;component/Koala.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                sr.Stream.CopyTo(ms);
                _photo = ms.ToArray();
            }

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private byte[] _photo;
        public byte[] Photo
        {
            get
            {
                return _photo;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Mainpage.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ByteToImageConverter x:Name="byteToImageConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Image Width="320" Height="240" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Path=Photo, Converter={StaticResource byteToImageConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the image was included in the project as a resource.

**UPDATE**

I saw you used the following code in your project:

```
byte[] blob = new byte[(dr.GetBytes(11, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
dr.GetBytes(11, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length - 0);
    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
    using (MemoryStream msJpg = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bm.Save(msJpg, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        game.gameImage = msJpg.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

This code won't work. You use [`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) this code returns (according to msdn):

> The byte array from which this stream was created, or the underlying
>   array if a byte array was not provided to the MemoryStream constructor
>   during construction of the current instance.

To get to right array use the [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) function of the MemoryStream class:

```
byte[] blob = new byte[(dr.GetBytes(11, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
dr.GetBytes(11, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length - 0);
    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
    using (MemoryStream msJpg = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bm.Save(msJpg, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        game.gameImage = msJpg.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And with a little refactoring:

```
byte[] blob = new byte[(dr.GetBytes(11, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
dr.GetBytes(11, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blob))
{
    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
    using (MemoryStream msJpg = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bm.Save(msJpg, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        game.gameImage = msJpg.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I wrote a little program to test the file you gave me (renamed the file btw):
[SilverlightTestV2.zip](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DEB5DDFF6A505390!279)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace ByteTransformer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead("byteArray.dat"))
            {
                var bm = Image.FromStream(fs);

                using (MemoryStream msJpg = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bm.Save(msJpg, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    using (var ts = File.Create("out.jpg"))
                    {
                        var img = msJpg.ToArray();
                        ts.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program throws an ArgumentException on the line: `var bm = Image.FromStream(fs);`

Hence I think that or the file you gave me doesn't contain the actual byte array from the sql (aka you saved it wrong) or the byte array in the sql is corrupt. But since you can actual see the image I think you saved it wrong.

Comment: To tell the truth I have tested byte arrays in console applocation. And everything was worked. So I font think so that byte arrays could be corrupted.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev the byte array was indeed corrupted. Check my latest update

Comment: I have tested that in Console Application. Then I saved image in drive. It was displayed. I think so that problem is not here. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you save one of the blobs from sql to a file and put it online so I can run a few tests on it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here it is: https://blu002.mail.live.com/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0#!https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=89fd450cc0cc74da!cid=89FD450CC0CC74DA&id=89FD450CC0CC74DA%21110

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev I cant download that file. Removed or I dont have the rights. You can also email it to me: gerard.gunnewijk@live.nl

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev ps. put the file in public folder, then right click and share. There is the right url

Comment: this is not image. I convert byte array to string. This is not what you want? And ok. I am sending it to you via mail.

Comment: I am really tired because of this problem.(((((    But in my opinion the problem is: BindingExpression path error: 'gameImage' property not found on 'SilverlightWithWCFService.CustomerService.Game'.   
Application cannot see gameImage property.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev then how about posting the Games class to us.

Comment: Hey it seems that it is bug. It worked unexpectedly. İ have not changed anything.

Comment: İ am going to be crazy. ))  İs it possible? Why it is worked?

Comment: Sometimes restarting the webservice helps or before building doing a clean. And sometimes you can just pull your hair out...

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

It should be enough to assign the blob directly to your gameImage-Property in your method `GamesList`. The other code should be useless.

```
byte[] blob = new byte[(dr.GetBytes(11, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
dr.GetBytes(11, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
game.gameImage = blob;
```

Also when you call [GetBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) on the MemoryStream you will get the array that is passed in the ctor of the MemoryStream. In your case you will get an empty array or null. I´m not sure.

**Initial:**

Change the `ConvertByteArrayToBitMapImage` method to the following

```
 public BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitMapImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
   BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
   MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray);

   img.SetSource(memStream);

   return img;
 }
```

When you dispose the MemoryStream using the `using`-Statement, the stream gets set to closed. So can´t the BitmapImage read from the stream that is set by using `SetSource`.